# How to collect demographic data for Google Analytics in Xamarin.Forms with KSemenenko plugin?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, xamarin.forms, demographics

I'm using for first time Google Analytics on a mobile project, and I have some doubts with the plugin I'm using right now, is the following that:

https://github.com/KSemenenko/GoogleAnalyticsForXamarinForms

And also this is my initialisation code:

```
GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.TrackingId = Keys.AnalyticsKey;
GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.AppId = Globals.PackageName; 
GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.AppName = Globals.ApplicationName;
GoogleAnalytics.Current.Config.AppVersion = Globals.Version;
GoogleAnalytics.Current.InitTracker();
```

This is working perfectly, also my custom metrics, but I need access to demographics information to create groups of users based on age/gender so... I don't know how to implement that part with this plugin.

Maybe I need other one? I'm working with Xamarin.Forms PCL project for Android and iOS, just in case.

Hope you could help me on this, i'm a little lost.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not use this plugin:
- iOS app crashes at background mode (bug with Timers/Repeaters)
- its not official Google library

Take a look at https://appcenter.ms, its official Microsoft (read more about Analytics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/)

Comment: yeah, I know about appcenter, but is a client requirement use Google Analytics. Any recommended plugin instead Ksemenenko?